# Execute Scala Futures in serial one after the other

Tags: scala, future

Given a method that returns a `Future` like this...

```
def myMethod(name: String, count: Int, default: Boolean): Future[Unit] = {
  ...
}
```

... I need to invoke it N times, so I've defined a list of tuples containing the parameters to be passed:

```
val paramList = List(
  ("text1", 22, true),
  ("text2", 55, true),
  ("text3", 77, false)
)
```

How do I invoke `myMethod` with `Future.traverse`?

```
Future.traverse(paramList)(myMethod _).tupled(/* how do I pass the current tuple here? */)
```

Comment: You don't seriously mean serial?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

```
val futuresFromSequence: Future[List[Unit]] = Future.sequence(paramList.map { 
  case (a,b,c) => myMethod(a,b,c) 
})

val futuresFromTraverse: Future[List[Unit]] = Future.traverse(paramList)(x => x match {
  case(a,b,c) => myMethod(a,b,c)
})
```

Note that `traverse` takes some collection and a function from an item of that collection to a future, `sequence` instead takes a list of futures and folds it to a future of list.

If you want to stick with the `tupled` syntax (which I personally dislike):

```
Future.traverse(paramList)(x => (myMethod _).tupled(x))
```

As noted in the comments you may want to run them in serial (although it's not 100% clear from the question), in that case you can use `foldLeft` and `flatMap` to chain future execution:

```
myList.foldLeft(Future(List.empty[Unit]))((prevFuture, currentTuple) => {
  for {
    prev <- prevFuture
    curr <- (myMethod _).tupled(currentTuple)
  } yield prev :+ curr
})
```

Where basically the first generator waits for the future in the accumulator to complete before launching the new one, this also returns a `Future[List[Unit]]`.

Comment: This will not run the futures one after the other.  All of them will run in parallel.

Comment: Op hasn't specified that, if he needs to run them in sequence he can use `flatMap` and for comprehension, but that's OP decision.

Comment: actuality the post title is "Execute Scala Futures in serial one after the other". How can it be implement with flatMap?

Comment: You may be right, the title actually contradict the body of the question, I have added the code necessary to run the future in sequence.

Comment: Yes, I need to execute the futures one after another... so your last update is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a note... to make your code compile, I needed to replace Future(List.empty[Unit])) with Future(List.empty[Any])).

Comment: @j3d it depends on your method signature, if it returns a `Unit` using `List.empty[Unit]` works, if it doesn't then you need to change the list type accordingly.